# Extract emails from a field having multiple words in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

In my MySQL table, I've a column-Residence_Address1. But it has other columns' values also in it. I want to extract email ids from the field.

Sample data.

eg.,

```
abcs12@yahoo.com,abcs@gmail.com,cityname
cityname,zipcode,abcs@gmail.com
abcs@officedomain.com,cityname,abc@gmail.com
apartment,streetname,cityname,abc@gmail.com,abcd@yahoo.com
```

If I tried this way:

```
select 
concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(ResidenceAddress1, '@', '1'), ' ', -1)), '@gmail.com') as mail
,ResidenceAddress1
from mytable
```

1) It merges data like this. Output:
`abcs12@gmail.com`
instead of abcs@gmail.com

2)It fetches email along with address.Output:`apartment,streetname,cityname,abc@gmail.com`
Instead of abc@gmail.com from a row.

I tried this way.

```
select concat(substring_index((substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', 2)),'@gmail',1),'@gmail.com') as mail, residence_address1
 from mytable
where Residence_Address1!="" and Residence_Address1 like '%gmail%'
```

1) It didn't merge the record like yahoo id with gmail id.

2) But it gives the full address along with email id.

eg.streetname,cityname,gmailid.

Above attempts were mainly fetching gmail ids.Instead of fetching only gmail id, I want to extract all emails from a row. Only emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        TRIM(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(ResidenceAddress1, '@gmail', '1')
                , ' ', -1)
            , ',', -1)
        )
        , '@gmail.com') AS mail
    ,ResidenceAddress1
FROM mytable
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (`ResidenceAddress1` varchar(58))
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    (`ResidenceAddress1`)
VALUES
    ('abcs12@yahoo.com,abcs@gmail.com,cityname'),
    ('cityname,zipcode,abcs@gmail.com'),
    ('abcs@officedomain.com,cityname,abc@gmail.com'),
    ('apartment,streetname,cityname,abc@gmail.com,abcd@yahoo.com')
;
```

Result:

```
| mail           | ResidenceAddress1                                          |
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| abcs@gmail.com | abcs12@yahoo.com,abcs@gmail.com,cityname                   | 
| abcs@gmail.com | cityname,zipcode,abcs@gmail.com                            | 
| abc@gmail.com  | abcs@officedomain.com,cityname,abc@gmail.com               | 
| abc@gmail.com  | apartment,streetname,cityname,abc@gmail.com,abcd@yahoo.com |
```

***Edited:***

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        TRIM(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                         IF(LOCATE('@yahoo', ResidenceAddress1), ResidenceAddress1, ''),
                         '@yahoo', 1)
                , ' ', -1)
            , ',', -1)
        )
        , IF(LOCATE('@yahoo', ResidenceAddress1), '@yahoo', '')
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(IF(LOCATE('@yahoo', ResidenceAddress1), ResidenceAddress1, ''), '@yahoo', -1), ',', 1)
    ) AS mail
    ,ResidenceAddress1
FROM mytable
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45be8d/5)

Comment: Oh.It won't work when we extract yahoo id from a record as yahoo ids are like atyahoo.com and atyahoo.co.in. Here we are appending .com with all the ids even if its .com or .co.in.

Comment: I too tried with Locate after dropping a message here. Thank you. Thank you for all your help.